# Will Cloudflare still cache files behind xsendfile

Tags: caching, cloudflare, x-sendfile

I have set up a Wordpress Woocommerce storefront. I want to set up downloadable products which will be downloaded via XSendFile module.

However, my download files are quite big (50mb approx) and so am planning to set up Cloudflare to cache the download files so I don't exceed my bandwidth limit from my hosting service.

My question is, will Cloudflare cache files that are linked through Apache's XSendFile module?

Sorry if this is a basic question. I'm just trying to figure out whether this set up will work or whether I will need to find an alternative solution.

NOTE: Forgot to add that the download files are pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on if we are proxying the record that it is on (www, for example). It is also important to note that we wouldn't cache third-party resources at all, if it is structured in some way that is not directly on the domain.

I would also recommend reviewing [what CloudFlare caches](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) by default.